# Python command/package for researching substrings?

Tags: python, string, replace

Does anyone knows how to do similar in Python to Bash' `seq` ?

For example, I would like to **search** for a line in a document that contains the chain of characters "measurement = abc" and replace "abc" with something of my own (using `"{}".format()` or something like it).

Do I need to check each string/substring in the document with an iterative loop or is there a built-in command or package in Python that already does that ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this with the regex implementation in Python (built-in re module).

This can be done with a [positive lookbehind assertion](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax).

> (?<=...) Matches if the current position in the string is preceded by a match for ... that ends at the current position.

```py
import re

data = "measurement = abc some other text measurement = abc some other text"

data = re.sub(r'(?<=measurement\s=\s)abc', '123', data) # positive lookbehind assertion

print(data)  # "measurement = 123 some other text measurement = 123 some other text"
```

Comment: Thank you @ChrisOram, it seems to be working. I'll try to fiddle around with the re package as it seems really powerful.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear it.